# Scrolling content when mouse is over a button with absolute position (button should remain clickable)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to scroll a content while the mouse is over a div or a button. This is important because it feels like the app is stuck if you cannot scroll. But the button should remain clickable. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Open example https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-wood-bqhxh?file=/src/App.js
2. Hover over the green button
3. Scroll with the mouse wheel

**Desired Behavior**
You can scroll the container

**Actual Behavior**
You can't scroll the container

p.s. I know you can use `pointer-events: none` so that you can keep scrolling but this prevents button clicks.

Comment: What OS/Browser are you using? It works as desired with Linux/XFCE/Firefox

Comment: @JensV hey I'm using MacOS with Chromium browser. I've tested it on firefox, doesn't work for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could achieve this by extending wheel event on button to scroll event on the scrollable div.

Checkout this pen:
https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-forest-z8f9b

Note: This may not be an optimal solution. But, it works for your case!

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked for me! Cheers

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you.. Please accept the answer.

Comment: Done! Thank you once again.